# PHP multiply arrays

Tags: php

I have 2 arrays like these, the idea is to do matrix multiplication using array_map or the most efficient way.

```
$array1= [10, 11, 12];
$array2= [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]] ;
```

I currently use this way, which works but does not seem to be very efficient, in addition to generating an annoying warning:
Warning: Undefined array key 0...... One warning for each element

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++) {
            for ($j = 0; $j < count($array2[0]); $j++) {             
                $resultado[$i] += $array1[$j] * $array2[$j][$i];
            }
        }
```

For the data I show, the correct answer is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 138
    [1] => 171
    [2] => 204
)
```